# In what format is NSData when appended to a NSMutableURLRequest?

Tags: php, ios, nsdata, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm using `NSMutableURLRequest` to send data to my PHP server.  This is how I create the request:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[@"whatever" objectForKey:@"message"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  //converting strings to NSData
[body appendData:[textParams objectForKey:key]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

My question is, in what format is the data received by the server in? I.E. `$_POST['message']`, would that be in binary, hex, base64, regular string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "message" value will come through as a string. In your PHP you can do:

```
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

Though your code has an issue. You need the following lines per text value you want to post:

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", @"message"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *text = ... // the text value to post for "message"
[body appendData:[text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  //converting strings to NSData
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

You were trying to call `objectForKey:` on a string literal. You can't do that. Also, you were adding `textParams`. I don't know what that is supposed to be but you need the above lines for each value you post. Perhaps those params need to be part of `text`.

Comment: The original code cycles through textParams and adds them to body. Hence the objectForKey... I agree that $message will be a string once the post value is assigned.  The thing is that I'm adding encrypted NSData objects to body. When I receive them in PHP to decrypt them is where I had my doubt. Were they arriving in hex, etc.? Apparently they arrive in 'string' format and I have to convert them to binary to go through the decrypting process.

Comment: The data arrives in the format you send it. If you send strings you get strings. If you send encrypted strings you get encrypted strings. If you send raw binary data you get raw binary data. If you send a data encoded into a base 64 string then you get the base 64 string. In all cases, the PHP side will need to reverse whatever transformation, if any, done before sending the value.